# get all pagination numbers inside div _ puppeteer

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, puppeteer

I need to extract all numbers inside a div(pagination numbers + links):

```
<div id="paging">
    <div class="pagingBlock">&nbsp; 
        <a class="pagingBlock">
            <!-- current page -->
            <b>1</b> 
        </a>,&nbsp;
        <a onclick="this.grid.changePage(2);return false;">2</a>
        <a onclick="this.grid.changePage(3);return false;">3</a>
        <a onclick="this.grid.changePage(4);return false;">4</a>
        <a onclick="this.grid.changePage(5);return false;">5</a>
        <a onclick="this.grid.changePage(6);return false;">6</a>
</div>
</div>
```

this is my code:

```
let value = await page.evaluate(() =>{
    
    let elements = document.querySelector('.pagingBlock').textContent
    
    
    console.log(elements)
    })
```

but it gets undefined.
how can I traverse inside a div?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const numbers = await page.evaluate(() => Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll('#paging a'),
  a => a.innerText.trim(),
));
console.log(numbers);
```